# Executing commands with one pipe in C

Tags: c, shell

The code is part of a simple shell program in C.
First command gets saved in args1 and the second one in args2
The problem is that only the second command gets executed.
Most of the code is from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xbLgZpOBi8)

```
void run_piped_commands(char user_input[]){

    char* args1[64]; char* args2[64];

    (user input into arguments...)

    pid_t pid;
    int pipefds[2];
    int pid1, pid2;

    if (pipe(pipefds) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == -1)
    {
        perror("fork 1 error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (pid1 == 0) //child1
    {
        close(pipefds[0]); 
        dup2(pipefds[1], 1);
        close(pipefds[1]);

        execvp(args1[0], args1);
        perror("child 1 error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid2 = fork();

    if (pid2 == -1)
    {
        perror("fork 2 error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid2 == 0) //child2
    {
        close(pipefds[1]);
        dup2(pipefds[0], 0);
        close(pipefds[0]);

        execvp(args2[0], args2);
        perror("child 2 error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    close(pipefds[0]); 
    close(pipefds[1]); 
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
}
```

I can also post the part of code where user input gets parsed into arguments if necessary

Comment: Please add the contents of arg1 printed just before calling execvp.

Comment: Sorry not a native speaker so my eng probably sucks, but if I understood correctly you want me to print the contents of args1 right before calling execvp? If that's the case, nothing gets printed

Comment: You are doing fine with the language, just provide [A Minimal Complete Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Turns out i just had to move close(pipefds[1]) above dup2(pipefds[1], 1) in the first child. I'm not too sure why it works this way though. Also thanks for the info, I didn't know there was a specific template when asking questions.

Comment: Actually your code looks fine to me, while your modification makes no sense since you can close the fd only after you have duplicated it to the appropriate standard input or output.